# Doubt in Zariski's Topology

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra

Chapter 1, Exercise $17$ for Introduction to Commutative Algebra says that

> For each $f\in A$, let $X_f$ denote the complement of $V(f)$ in $X = Spec (A)$. The
> sets $X_f$ are open. Show that they form a basis of open sets for the Zariski
> topology.

How should I prove that this is a basis. I am using the fact that any open set can be written as union of basis elements. Please check if this works. Thanks.

I recall that $V(E)= V(\mathfrak{E})$ where $\mathfrak{E}$ is the smallest ideal containing $E \subset A$. Thus $X_f=spec(A) \setminus V(\mathfrak{E})$
Thus $X_f$ is an open set.

Conversely any open set of $spec(A)$ is of the form $$spec(A) \setminus V(\mathfrak{E})=spec(A) \setminus V( \bigcup_{f \in \mathfrak{E}}\{f\})=spec(A) \setminus  \bigcap_{f \in \mathfrak{E}}V( \{f\})=\bigcup_{f \in \mathfrak{E}}\Big(spec(A)-V( \{f\} \Big)=\bigcup_{f \in \mathfrak{E}}\Big(X_f \Big)$$

Comment: The $V(f)$'s form a closed base for the Zariski topology (by definition) so their complements form an open base.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: It's what you reasoning comes down to. So yes.